# WPF: How to bind to a property of another's control binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm creating a form using WPF with MVVM.

There I have my View with its DataSource bound to my ViewModel object. Great.

In my xaml, I have an ItemsControl with its ItemSource bound to ViewModel.MyCollectionOfFoo.

For every Foo object in this collection, I'm creating a control with bindings to this foo object, but I also need to bind a Command to every one of them.

This Command is a property of my ViewModel object (witch is the DataSource of the View).

Since I'm inside the ItemsControl, how to get the reference to the ViewModel.DoSomethingCommand?

It's like binding to a property of another's control binding...

Thanks,

André Carlucci

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<... Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CommandPropertyOfYourViewModel, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                      AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

This will use the DataContext of your Window as the binding source instead of the current DataContext.